# How to create column in table and fill with select query in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to create new columns in a table and fill it with calculations with using other tables.

An example code looks like this

```
select 
    a.Segment || b.Segment || c.Segment as Comb_Segment
from
    table_a a
inner join
    table_b b on a.Id = b.Id
inner join
    table_c c on a.Id = c.Id
```

Here's my data and expected output

table_a:

```
+--------+----+---------+
| Period | Id | Segment |
+--------+----+---------+
|     12 |  1 | X       |
+--------+----+---------+
```

table_b

```
+--------+----+---------+
| Period | Id | Segment |
+--------+----+---------+
|     11 |  1 | C       |
+--------+----+---------+
```

table_c

```
+--------+----+---------+
| Period | Id | Segment |
+--------+----+---------+
|     10 |  1 | A       |
+--------+----+---------+
```

expected output table_a

```
+--------+----+---------+--------------+
| Period | Id | Segment | Comb_Segment |
+--------+----+---------+--------------+
|     12 |  1 | X       | XCA          |
+--------+----+---------+--------------+
```

white doing this query I also want to create a column in "table_a" called Comb_Segment and fill it with this "Comb_Segment".

Any ideas?

Comment: could you please provide your sample data and expected output?

Comment: ohh @zealous please edit your answer.( sorry for this, we solved it with him on chat, but I think he forgot to edit his answer. )

Comment: You have accepted @forpas answer, so that is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the new column with:

```
ALTER TABLE table_a ADD Comb_Segment TEXT;
```

and then update it like this:

```
UPDATE table_a
SET Comb_Segment = (
  SELECT a.Segment || b.Segment || c.Segment   
  FROM table_a a 
  INNER JOIN table_b b ON b.Id = a.Id
  INNER JOIN table_c c ON c.Id = a.Id
  WHERE a.Id = table_a.Id
);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ua2DXbM2Lon6jiCVj89YsB/1).

Or simpler:

```
UPDATE table_a
SET Comb_Segment = 
  Segment ||
  (SELECT b.Segment FROM table_b b WHERE b.Id = table_a.Id) ||
  (SELECT c.Segment FROM table_c c WHERE c.Id = table_a.Id);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/73Eqciv3CdQ7XcHBu7fRAD/0).

Results:

```
| Period | Id  | Segment | Comb_Segment |
| ------ | --- | ------- | ------------ |
| 12     | 1   | X       | XCA          |
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following using `group_concat`, here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oaqjxRfgMS1KGyBjFray2d/1).

```
select
    a.period,
    u.id,
    a.segment,
    group_concat(u.segment, '') as comb_segment
from
(
  select
    *
  from table_a

  union all

  select
      *
  from table_b

  union all

  select
      *
  from table_c
) u

join table_a a
on u.id = a.id

group by
    a.period,
    u.id,
    a.segment
```

Output:

```
| Period | Id  | Segment | comb_segment |
| ------ | --- | ------- | ------------ |
| 12     | 1   | X       | ACX          |
```

Comment: but I also want to save Comb_Segment as a new column into my table_a. This still wont create new column.

Comment: @EgeÇıkrıkçı try now. I have provided you demo as well.

Comment: I think I couldnt manage to explain myself well. Let me rephrase my question. Lets say after having this output, I want to create a new table "table_x", I want to create a new column 'comb_segment" on "table_x" and I want to write table_a.comb_segment into table_x.comb_segment. Can you also explain that too please.

Comment: this is what I asked for actually. I said "white doing this query I also want to create a column in "table_a" called Comb_Segment and fill it with this "Comb_Segment"." I'm sorry but your solutions still not creating new column in table_a. Something like ALTER TABLE table_a ADD COLUMN comb_segment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214306/discussion-between-ege-cikrikci-and-zealous).